# Keep element active until page reloads ignoring mouseout

Tags: css, navigation, focus

The top menus at [www.petersencreative.com](http://www.petersencreative.com) use CSS (and some CSS3) to provide the smooth transitions. My problem is that if you click a link and then mouseoff the link, it starts to descend again. Is there a way to keep it up (fnnnrrr!) once it's been clicked and then mouseoff?

I've looked at using :active but that only for when the mouse is down. :focus only seems to work for keyboard navigation. Am looking at using a bit of jQuery or is there a way to do it using CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with CSS, using `:target` selector.

Comment: I think it could be used if it were a one-page site and they were all anchor links. e.g. the tabbed interface on http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/target.en.html. That's not even slightly IE friendly though, and makes the browser scroll position jump around (like any anchor link would).

Comment: @OllyHodgson yes, and yes - it does not work in IE lesser than 9.